# I sent bitcoin to the wrong address

Tags: buy-bitcoins

How can I learn who has access the the address that my btc were incorrectly sent to? I look in btc.com and see that the btc was sent and completed, and unspent. It's just sitting somewhere on the blockchain? How can I contact the person who has access to the key?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to find/contact that person.

You are acting pseudonymously in the bitcoin network. You don't know who owns the adress if the owner doesn't tell you that he/she is the owner.

Comment: So these btc are just sitting, unspent, in a random node or hash on the blockchain, and there is no way for me to access or request access to them... how can I tell if there is just traffic delaying the transfer of my btc into my exchange?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand you second question "how can I tell ...."

Comment: I guess I just want to know what happens to that btc? btc.com shows that it was transacted and unspent. It's frustrating to think that it will just sit there unused.

Comment: Yes, as the adress has (probably) no owner (no one has the private key for that adress), these bitcoins will probably never be used/spent.

Comment: Can the exchange that I was intending to send these btc (i submitted a ticket) somehow request or retrieve the funds?

Comment: Once the bitcoins are on that adress (once the transaction is in a block of the blockchain), there is NO way for you to get them back.

Comment: You can consider those coins to be in an unbreakable transparant box that everybody (that knows the location) can forever see, but nobody can ever open.